# Inserir quebra de página ao gerar PDF com Snappy PDF no Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Estou gerando um PDF no Laravel usando o Snappy PDF. O problema é que não está quebrando a página no lugar que deveria. 
Já tentei usar o `page-break-after: always` do CSS no local onde deveria existir a quebra de página mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando a classe:

```
.page-break{
   page-break-after: always;
}
```

no local onde eu queria a quebra.